# Library for chat bot conversation flow

Tags: c#, automation, chat, artificial-intelligence

I want a chat bot library with these specific requirements:

- I should be able to integrate it with my messenger of choice to which I have API access.
- I can design a set of conversational strategies. Only one strategy is selected randomly at the start.
- Each strategy is a sequence of predefined messages that should be sent to a user.
- Each message may be defined in multiple variants, one variant is picked randomly.
- A strategy may have conversational branches which are triggered by a user reaction (keyword/regex parsing).
- If user asks a question expected by keyword/regex parsing, the bot should answer with a predefined message.
- It should be able to gather information using predefined questions and parsing answers.
- It should look like a human. It shouldn't send the same message again and again.
- If user doesn't answer, the bot should ping him with a set of predefined messages.
- At reaching some conversational point the bot should stop and allow operator to continue instead.
- It's a plus to be able to gather statistics on which strategies or message variants are more successful (defined by operator or keywords or conversation length).
- If it uses AI, it should work with Russian language. Being able to answer not predefined questions is a plus but not necessary.
- If it's not free, it should be cheap enough for non-commercial pet project.